# Why there is no std::string::append/insert recivieng rvalue string?

Tags: c++, stdstring

```
basic_string& append(basic_string&& Right) {
    if (Right.capacity() >= size() + Right.size())
    {
        swap(Right);
        insert(0, Right);
        return *this;
    }
    return append(Right); // lvalue reference overload
}
```

Is it just lack of committee time or there is some problem with my implementation? *`string::swap` is `noexcept`, assume `char_traits::move` `noexcept` too*

Comment: Hmm, it's just kinda weird.  This is not a particularly useful feature that I can imagine myself ever wishing for.  Normally with move-semantics the intention is to yield ownership of the object, not use it as some kind of hack that prevents an allocation in a very specific and uncommon scenario.  By all means, do this in your program if it's the kind of behavior you want.  It should not be part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @paddy look at `string operator+(string&, string&&)`

Comment: @paddy Right is moved-out or temporary, so there is no reason not t use it. Actually all rvalue receiving functions of STL containers do this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right is moved-out or temporary, so modification of s2 doesn't change semantics (you cann't observe state, or state is not defined (moved-out))